# How to fix 4 arc issue when converting pdf to dxf using inkscape?

Tags: python, pdf, svg, inkscape, dxf

I'm trying to convert a pdf file to a dxf file using the `inkscape` command.
I converted a pdf file to a svg file first and converted this to dxf file.

This is the `inkscape` command I've used:

```
inkscape input.svg --export-type=dxf --export-extension=org.ekips.output.dxf_outlines -o output.dxf
```

As you can see, instead of one perfect circle, I got a circle made up of 4 arcs.

[image: circles]

I want a smooth, single-componented circle. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Inkscape is open source so I imagine you would [download the source code](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape), figure out where the bug is and fix it.

Comment: Is it possible to group these 4 arcs? I don't want them to be selected separately.

Comment: I mean, using inkscape command or other library such as ezdxf.

Comment: I tried to group arcs using ezdxf but it didn't give me a clue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no circle primitive in PDF. All circles in PDF have to be made from several curves (four is usual). So, unless your convertor has a way to detect and reconstruct circles, you're stuck.

Comment: can't I reconstruct a circle using Python libraries such as ezdxf or inkscape?

Comment: any other constructive way?